# Yii2 theme baseurl

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to echo Yii2 theme base url using this [official link.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-theming.html)

```
<?php 
    $theme = $this->theme;
    echo $theme->baseUrl; // line 119
?>
```

but it return me this **error**:

> **PHP Notice** – yii\base\ErrorException Trying to get property of
>   non-object
>
> 1. in E:\wamp\www\yii2-app\frontend\views\site\index.php at line 119

Why this error? is it not possible to get Yii2 theme base url?

Comment: show your config main.php components views  code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems that you component is not properly defined .. be sure you have a theme defined in you components section eg:

> ```
>   return [
>       'components' => [
>           'view' => [
>               'theme' => [
>                   'basePath' => '@app/themes/basic',
>                   'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/basic',
>                   'pathMap' => [
>                       '@app/views' => '@app/themes/basic',
>                   ],
>               ],
>           ],
>       ],
> ];
> ```

Comment: I got your point, thank you. I have not defined component properly. [Refrence](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html#$theme-detail)

Comment: I think you are a part of Yii core team developer ;)

Comment: Thank you very much  .. but no  .. I'm just a simple  coder .. I'm a freelance ..